# AlamoFireObjectMapper cannot save data response in object array

Tags: ios, json, swift, get, alamofire

I am using AlamoFireObjectMapper to try and and map some simple JSON to some class models. It seems that I am able to correctly retrieve the JSON and print it, however when I try and append my response to an array of my class-type it doesn't work.

Sample JSON:
    [image: SampleJson]

```
class MovieResults: Mappable {

var movieResults: [MovieInfo]?

required init?(map: Map) {
    mapping(map: map)
   }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    // An array of objects
    self.movieResults <- map["results"]
   }
}

class MovieInfo: Mappable {

var movieTitle: String?
var movieID: Int?
var movieRating: String?
var movieReleaseDate: String?
var inTheaters: Bool?

var movieResults: [MovieInfo]?


required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.movieTitle <- map["title"]
    self.movieID <- map["id"]
    self.movieRating <- map["rating"]
    self.movieReleaseDate <- map["release_date"]
    self.inTheaters <- map["in_theaters"]
   }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class resultViewController: UITableViewController {

var searchTerm: String?
var movieArray = [MovieInfo]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchAPI(search: searchTerm!)
}

func fetchAPI(search: String) {
    let gboxAPI = "rK5M0dCTUd268hk121BpNpEAxMOmFuNh"
    let URL = "http://api-public.guidebox.com/v1.43/US/\(gboxAPI)/search/movie/title/\(searchTerm!)/fuzzy"


    Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { ( response: DataResponse<MovieResults>) in

        let result = response.result.value

        if let movies = result?.movieResults {
            for item in movies {
                self.movieArray.append(item) //this doesn't work
                print(item.movieTitle) //this works
            }
        }
    }

    /* This doesn't print anything
        for some reason my array isn't truly being 
        popluated in the above fetchAPI call
    */
    for item in movieArray {
        print(item.movieTitle)
    }

}
override func tableView(_ tablView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return movieArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")

    let movieItem = movieArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = movieItem.movieTitle
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = movieItem.movieRating

    return cell

    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can print, but not store my data. That just doesn't click with me.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to create an object of the `Mappable` class so that you can append data to it. Rather you can create another model class and use its object.

```
class movieModel: NSObject {
    var movieTitle: String?
    var movieID: Int?
    var movieRating: String?
    var movieReleaseDate: String?
    var inTheaters: Bool?
}
```

Now create objects of this class in `resultViewController` and use it to store movie details.

```
class resultViewController: UITableViewController {
    let movieArray: [movieModel]? //create array of movieModel object
    .......
      ........
        if let movies = result?.movieResults {
           for item in movies {
              let movie = movieModel()//create object of movieModel
              movie.movieTitle = item.movieTitle
              movie.movieID = item.movieID
              movie.movieRating = item.movieRating
              movie.movieReleaseDate = item.movieReleaseDate
              movie.inTheaters = item.inTheaters

              self.movieArray.append(self.movie)
              print(item.movieTitle)
           }
       }
    ........
}
```

Comment: let movieArray: [movieModel]? does not create an array, that makes a property of movieModel, also [movieModel] has no member 'append', and even if it did that wouldn't work as it is a defined as a constant with 'let'. Thanks for the help though, I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 0):

The request is asynchronous. The block is not executed until a response is received from the server.
Your for-loop is executed directly after firing the request. Run `self.tableView.reloadData()` after appending the new objects and it should work.